# Loading webview in content page shows page first in xamarin forms in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I am creating Xamarin Forms application which targets iOS and Android. We are showing web view on content page when application loads having login page. In iOS, when application loads, it directly loads webview on content page but in Android, it fist loads content page for 2-3 seconds and then loads web view which looks very bad in terms user experience.

Below is content page which only contains webview. But before loading webview control on screen, it shows below screen with application name, header bar and blank body for Android environment.

[image]

**Questions:**

Is there any way we can directly load webview in android?
or can we add some good UI for android?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because that is normally where some kind of splash screen would live.

If you create a style something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to your activity like:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
```

Then it should be gone. If you have a theme already, just add the XML inside the `style` tags to the current theme.